# Mapping thru state object and testing multiple nested arrays without multiple return values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, filter, jsx

I'm (obviously) very new to React and Javascript, so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question. Basically I have an array of objects in this.state, each with its own nested array, like so:

```
    foods: [
      {
        type: "sandwich",
        recipe: ["bread", "meat", "lettuce"]
      },
      {
        type: "sushi",
        recipe: ["rice", "fish", "nori"]
      }, ...
```

I've already written a function that maps through the state objects and runs .includes() on each object.recipe to see if it contains a string.

```
    const newArray = this.state.foods.map((thing, i) => {
      if (thing.recipe.includes(this.state.findMe)) {
        return <p>{thing.type} contains {this.state.findMe}</p>;
      } return <p>{this.state.findMe} not found in {thing.type}</p>;
    });
```

The main issue is that .map() returns a value for each item in the array, and I don't want that. I need to have a function that checks each object.recipe, returns a match if it finds one (like above), but also returns a "No match found" message if NONE of the nested arrays contain the value it's searching for. Right now this function returns "{this.state.findMe} not found in {thing.type}" for each object in the array.

I do know .map() is supposed to return a value. I have tried using forEach() and .filter() instead, but I could not make the syntax work. (Also I can't figure out how to make this function a stateless functional component -- I can only make it work if I put it in the render() method -- but that's not my real issue here. )

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {

    foods: [
      {
        type: "sandwich",
        recipe: ["bread", "meat", "lettuce"]
      },
      {
        type: "sushi",
        recipe: ["rice", "fish", "nori"]
      },
      {
        type: "chili",
        recipe: ["beans", "beef", "tomato"]
      },
      {
        type: "padthai",
        recipe: ["noodles", "peanuts", "chicken"]
      },
    ],

    findMe: "bread",

  }

  render() {

    const newArray = this.state.foods.map((thing, i) => {
      if (thing.recipe.includes(this.state.findMe)) {
        return <p>{thing.type} contains {this.state.findMe}</p>;
      } return <p>{this.state.findMe} not found in {thing.type}</p>;
    });

   return (
     <div>
       <div>
         <h3>Results:</h3>
             {newArray}
       </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Array.reduce` for this:

```
const result = foods.reduce((acc,curr)=> curr.recipe.includes(findMe) ? `${curr.type} contains ${findMe}`:acc ,'nothing found')

console.log(result)
```

Though if the ingredient is found in more than one recipe it will only return the last one.

Alternatively, you could use a `map` and a `filter`:

```
const result = foods.map((thing, i) => {
      if (thing.recipe.includes(findMe)) {
        return `${thing.type} contains ${findMe}`;
      }}).filter(val=>!!val)

console.log(result.length?result[0]:'nothing found')
```

Comment: Perfect! Array.reduce was what I needed, it's working in my code now. In my final app I shouldn't have any "ingredients" appearing in more than one "recipe", but I saved your map/filter solution for future reference. Thank you so much!